# Specifying -Djava.ext.dirs causes i18 issues

Tags: java, jar, internationalization, classpath, aspose

Facing a strange java issue. When this command-line parameter is passed, it screws up my output wrt internationalizaton.

Background is I am trying to convert a hebrew Word document to PDF using Aspose library.

It works as expected when "-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Java\jre1.8.0_77\lib" is NOT passed during application start-up. But the moment we pass this, some of the date fields are no longer retained in Hebrew text in output but becomes English rather ... causing content mismatch between input & output files.

The directory being passed here is OOTB java installation directory, I am really surprised why that may be causing such behavior.

**Works** : java.exe -Duser.language=he -Duser.country=IL -cp Aspose.Words.jar;. Sample (output will be ‏‏21 פברואר 2017)

**Doesn't work** : java.exe -Duser.language=he -Duser.country=IL -cp Aspose.Words.jar;. -Djava.ext.dirs="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib" Sample (output will be 21 February 2017)

Any idea why this might be the case ?

Thanks

Comment: Any idea why this could be happening ?

Comment: Please share the sample input document via any free file sharer server e.g. Dropbox. I will investigate the issue and provide you more information on this. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.